# Understanding AlpineJS x-init and x-for

Tags: laravel, alpine.js

I have something that i've been working on which I got working but I'm not really sure why, hoping you can help understand.

The idea was to essentially have a console box which I update with logs that I receive through laravel echo.

```
         <div x-data="appState" class="w-10/12 m-auto" x-init="getLogs()" x-show="consoleShow">
            <div
                class="coding inverse-toggle h-60 overflow-y-scroll px-5 pt-4 shadow-lg text-gray-100 text-xs font-mono subpixel-antialiased 
              bg-gray-800  pb-6 pt-4 rounded-lg leading-normal overflow-hidden" id="consoleBox">
                <div class="top mb-2 flex flow-root static">
                    <div class="h-4 w-4 bg-red-500 rounded-full float-right cursor-pointer" x-on:click="consoleShow = false"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="mt-4 flex">
                    {{-- <span class="text-green-400">computer:~$</span> --}}
                    <p class="flex-1 typing items-center pl-2">
                        <template x-for="(log, index) in logs" :key="index">
                            <li class="list-none" x-text="log"></li>
                        </template>
                        <br>
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Then I within my appState in  tags

```
getLogs() {
                Echo.channel('logs').listen('.logs', (log) => {
                    // do what you need to do based on the event name and data
                    console.log(log);
                    this.logs.push(log.message.function+': '+log.message.task+' - '+log.message.status);
                
                    window.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent("scrollDown"));



                });

            }
```

It took my quite a while to get working, essentially i had issues with the x-for updating with new additions to the logs var.  However i managed to resolve it by adding getLogs() to the x-init of my container div.

My understanding was that the x-init was only there to execute when the element is rendered.  I don't really understand why having the function in x-init would allow the x-for to update correctly.  Could anyone provide some insights to help wrap my head around this?

Adding in a cutback example of the code:

```
const appState = {
events: [],


async loadEvent(event) {
                fetch("/admin/scrapeEvent", {
                        method: "POST",
                        headers: {
                            "Content-Type": "application/json",
                            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': document.head.querySelector('meta[name=csrf-token]').content,
                            Accept: "application/json",
                        },
                        body: JSON.stringify(event)
                    })
                    .then(() => {
      
                    })
                    .catch(() => {
 
                    })
                    .finally(() => {
                        
                        this.retrieveLoadedEventsTable();  
                        
                    });
            },
 async retrieveLoadedEventsTable() {


                try {
                    let response = await fetch('/admin/findNewEvents/loaded');
                    let data = await response.json();

                    for (let item of data) item.disabled = true;
                    this.events = data;
                } catch (itsTheErrorObject) {
                    console.log("something went wrong");
                }

                

            }

}


<div x-data="appState" x-init="retrieveLoadedEventsTable()">
<template x-for="event, index in events" :key="event.id">
/** HTML that renders event.atrributes - Works fine on first load **/

</template>
</div>


<div x-data="appState" x-init="retrieveIncompleteEventsTable()">
 <x-button class="ml-3" x-bind:disabled="event.disabled" x-on:click="loadEvent(unloadedEvents[index])">
Load Event
</x-button>

/** This works fine to load my event into the sql table, i can confirm that it runs through and executes the finally in loadEvent, but the events in the template contained in the div with x-init with retrieveLoadedEventsTable does not update **/

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My understanding was that the `x-init` was only there to execute when the element is rendered.

No, [`x-init` directive](https://alpinejs.dev/directives/init) is called at initialization phase of an element. At that point Alpine.js has already created the data variables from `x-data` but it has not rendered anything (has not modified the DOM) yet. The `x-init` is the recommended place to put a function that e.g. calls an API then appends some variables defined in `x-data` or to create an event listener that (later) mutates the data like in your example.

After executing the functions from `x-init`, Alpine.js renders the component with the actual `logs` variable. When the event listener in your `getLogs()` function catches a new event and appends the `logs` variable, Alpine.js detects it and re-renders the respective parts of the DOM.

Comment: Ok, but i have issues replicating this in other scenarios.

I have something like


`const appState{
tableData,
showData(){-Loads data from SQL and updates tableData},
addData(){Adds new data to the SQL then reruns showData(), which should update tableData}
}`

Then I have a <div x-init="showData()"> with an <x-for on tableData> which renders fine on first load, but nothing gets added when a rerun showData() from addData()

Hope that makes sense. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Could you share this other component with some example data in your question? It should be working if `tableData` is a reactive Alpine.js variable.

Comment: Hey, tried to cut it down to make it more readable in the question.  Hopefully that makes sense, appreciate your help!

Comment: I noticed you have two separate `appState` components. That means they *do not share* the `events` variable! You need to use a common parent component that defines one common `events` variable or e.g. use the global [$store object](https://alpinejs.dev/globals/alpine-store) to share the data between the components.

Comment: You were spot on, modified the implementation to share an appState parent and did the x-inits on the parent. All working perfectly, make a lot more sense now. 

Does this mean that each x-data references its own set of vars or its own instance of an object? I'd really like to understand this better, any resources or ideas I could research to get a better grasp?

Thanks for your assistance.

Comment: Great! Yes, each component creates a new set of vars, but it can also access its parent(s) data (if their property names are unique/not overwritten by a child). The official documentation has a simple example in the [`x-data` scoping](https://alpinejs.dev/directives/data#scope) section. You can share data between components via events, with a common ancestor or through the global [$store object](https://alpinejs.dev/globals/alpine-store). Each approach has different use-cases.